# sqlite: No such table found(parent table) error while creating foreign key in child table

Tags: android

I have created one Member_Master table whose primary key is member_id in sqlite manager for android and creating foreign key in child table e.g Event_Master for member_id from Member_Master. I was getting `no such table found:Member_Master` error
But now I am getting the following error :

```
SQLiteManager: CREATE TABLE "main"."Events_Master" ("event_id" NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY  NOT 
NULL ,"event_name" TEXT NOT NULL ,"event_details" TEXT NOT NULL ,"event_start_date" 
DATETIME NOT NULL ,"event_end_date" DATETIME NOT NULL ,"event_time" DATETIME NOT NULL 
,"event_venue" TEXT NOT NULL ,"min_level" NUMERIC,"status_id" NUMERIC,"member_id" 
NUMERIC, foriegn key(member_id) references Member_Master(member_id)ON DELETE CASCADE ON
UPDATE CASCADE) [ near "member_id": syntax error ]

Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) 
[mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Please give me the solution. Since `Member_Master` table is already created and field name is `member_id` only.

Comment: are u update ur database version after changing ur table.

Comment: spelling of `foreign`.. correct it.. also remove `,` between `NUMERIC, foriegn key`

Comment: there was not the problem of foreign spelling.. i have solved the problem. And , should be there while declaring foreign key in sqlite manager I read somewhere and i did by taking , only. By the way thanks for your comment...

Comment: first u have to change or update ur database version den see ...

Comment: from where u are creating that third table ? from code itself or from sqlite manager and copying that file from assets folder to phone memory ? if you are using 2nd approach then try unistalling your app and install again.

Comment: creating the table from sqlite manager

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting no such table exception, the reason for this is that the table is not created.There can be few reasons like

1 ) The command you have used to create the table is is wrong (and could be a typing error also).

2 ) You are adding a table in an already existing database

When `Database` is created with specific number of tables you can not add more tables to it .
If you want to add more tables, you need to uninstall the application from your emulator and install the application again only then it shall create the new tables by re creating the database.
Or upgrade the database version , it shall drop all the tables once and then recreate the database.

Answer (score 1):

*Try `uninstalling` the app and `reinstall` it again. it works most of the times.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting no such table exception, then It is sure that the tables are not getting created.Have You written create Table query in your DatabaseAdapter class or simply adding a table from SqliteManager.
If you are creating tables dynamically, please write CREATE TABLE query and execute Query.